# Where does Kobato fit into the CLAMP multiverse?

Tags: kobato

*Kobato* includes characters from Chobits and Angelic Layer, as well as other CLAMP series, in its world. But it doesn't seem to be the same world as Chobits and Angelic Layer; for example, Chitose Hibiya's children don't appear to be persocoms.

Does *Kobato* take place in the same world as any other CLAMP series, or is it a standalone world that includes alternate versions of some characters?

(I haven't finished the series, so please use spoiler tags liberally.)

Comment: With maybe the exception of Yuuko, aren't all the CLAMP series pretty much "alternate universes"?

Comment: @JonLin Finding that out was my aim in asking this question. I was pretty sure that Angelic Layer and Chobits were meant to be exactly the same universe, spaced out by a couple years. At first I thought Kobato might also be in that universe, but various things don't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Kobato page on the CLAMP Wikia](http://clamp.wikia.com/wiki/Kobato.#Crossovers) has a fairly expansive list of ways that it fits within the multiverse. I'm not going to rewrite all of them, because that would be too long, so I'll just summarize them.

- The alternate versions of some characters show up.
- Her apartment complex shows up in other series (sometimes in alternate Japans).
- A picture of Clow and Yuuko shows up in an explanation of the worlds.
- Many characters have cameos.

Overall: some characters from non-modern-Japan show up with different identities, while series set in Japan are related to Kobato.

Comment: Good resource, but I'm still confused as to whether Kobato is in the same world as any of the other series, or a different world with recurrent characters and items. Is the answer "We don't know, it's ambiguous?"

Comment: It's the same world in the sense that it is in the same multiverse. In regards to being in the same universe within the same multiverse, it seems to be that it is within the "modern Japan" universe.

Comment: The wiki seems to suggest that the "modern Japan" universe is considered a separate world (within the same multiverse) from the world of Chobits and Angelic Layer, but possibly the same world as Card Captor Sakura, Legal Drug, xxxHolic, and others. I guess the point I'd like to clarify is "Is Kobato in the same world (within the shared multiverse) as any other CLAMP series?", and the answer would be yes if it is indeed the same world as Card Captor Sakura, xxxHolic, etc. If the answer is "Not enough information", I'll accept that too.